# How to get "build" and "target" C compiler with autoconf

Tags: cross-compiling, autoconf

In a cross environment, AC_PROG_CC finds the name of the target C compiler. In my setup I need to build some tools which run on the build machine, not on the target, so I also need a build system C compiler. I wonder if there is something like AC_PROG_CC to find the name of the build C compiler and also to set proper CFLAGS and linker flags.

Or should I have a separate configure file for the tools which run on the host and call autoconf recursively?

Many thanks for sharing your insights in this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In my setup I need to build some tools which run on the build machine, not on the target, so I also need a build system C compiler. I wonder if there is something like `AC_PROG_CC` to find the name of the build C compiler and also to set proper `CFLAGS` and linker flags.

[AX_PROG_CC_FOR_BUILD](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_prog_cc_for_build.html) is probably what you need since you want to set `CFLAGS`.

> Or should I have a separate configure file for the tools which run on the host and call autoconf recursively?

That's sort of what `AX_PROC_CC_FOR_BUILD` does.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for! Also that something like https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive exists is not so obvious from the autoconf documentation - thanks for the pointer!